# C# - MD5 hash not matching expected value

Tags: c#, character-encoding, md5

I am trying to generate a MD5 hash in C#, but I cannot retrieve the string that I am expecting.

Using an [MD5 Hash Generator](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php), the string `Hello World!` returns a hash of `ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c`.

Using this code:

```
string hash;
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello World!")));
}
```

returns `�\ab�S.�6^����\r�` which is problematic.

I suspect this is an issue to do with my encoding of the string. How can I retrieve the expected value?

**Edit**: As you can see, I do not have much (any) experience with using the MD5 hash - the aim of this question is to educate myself, rather than use the code to secure information.

Comment: `ComputeHash` returns a byte array. Any byte array can not be converted to string

Comment: That makes sense - I suppose a basic version of my question is "How do the online MD5 generator's work?!"...

Comment: @PTuckley they use a database which contain these hashes and try to match it against them.

Comment: Note that for educational purposes, you could actually write your own MD5 generator - it's not as hard as you might think. As a starting point, some description of the algorithm like the [MD5 RFC](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt) is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComputeHash()` returns a byte array. Use a method to convert it to your desired hex format, e.g. `BitConverter.ToString` and some string manipulatino to get rid of the hyphens:

```
    string hash;
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello World!")));
    }
    hash = hash.Replace("-", "");
```

Output: `ED076287532E86365E841E92BFC50D8C`

Comment: Why to replace with '-', what will be the problem if '-' is there in string?

Comment: Usually MD5 sums don't have hyphens and the expected output of OP was without them, of course they can be kept if you're fine with them

Answer (score 2):

The `ComputeHash()` returns a byte array. You have to convert that byte array into a string in hex notation.

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
        // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
        using(MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
           byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
           byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

           // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.Length);
           for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
           {
              // use "x2" for all lower case.
              sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
           }
           return sb.ToString();
        }
}
```

Comment: `MD5` being `IDisposable`, should be put into *using*, i.e. `using(MD5 md5 = ...) {...}`

Comment: `new StringBuilder(2 * hash.Length)` could be a bit more efficient than just `new StringBuilder()`; `.ToString("x2"); ` (note small "x" rather than capital "X")

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko thanks, I updated the sample. I noted in the comment about the "x2" and "X2".

Answer (score 1):

If you want `string` represenatation of the hash, you have to *encode* its `byte[]` representation:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
public string MD5Hash(String input) {
  using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create()) {
    return String.Concat(md5
      .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
      .Select(item => item.ToString("x2")));
  }
}

...
// hash == "ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c"
String hash = MD5Hash("Hello World!");
```